# Html form : submit values in uri

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, symfony, form-submit

I really need some help ^^ this issue is going to put me crazy... :)

Well i am using symfony2 and angularjs for my project :

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="" method="post">         
    <div class="form-group">
        <input  class="form-control" ng-model="inputSummoner" type="text" placeholder="Summoner" name="summoner" value="" required>                                                 
        <select class="form-control btn-primary" ng-model="inputRegion" ng-init="inputRegion = regions[0]"  ng-options="region for region in regions"></select>
    </div>                              
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Research</button>                                 
</form>
```

I need to get the input value and the select value and create a link
for exemple if the input is "hello" and the selected value "world"

When i click on Research i would like to go on this link :

```
myWebSiteUri/stats/Hello/World
```

The problem is that for the moment i get this :

```
myWebSiteUri/stats?input=Hello?select=World
```

This is not what i want...

I tried several ways and all were fails ...
My first idea was to use ng-model values and create the path manually but that didn't work :

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="{{"stats/"+inputSummoner+"/"+inputRegion}}" method="post">
```

If someone have an idea ...

Thanks in advance !!

Best regards,
CUETO Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow i found my mistake !!! xD

The fact is that i used wrong quotes ^^

```
action="{{"stats/"+inputSummoner+"/"+inputRegion}}"
```

And the good way was with simple quotes

```
action="{{'stats/'+inputSummoner+'/'+inputRegion}}"
```

I was about to do this another way but was not a good coding practice at all ^^